# What is the shortcut for lists indexing in Python3.5?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I want to get the column names so that I can add to the new data frame.

```
In [241]: cursor.description
Out[241]: 
(('a', None, None, None, None, None, None),
 ('b', None, None, None, None, None, None),
 ('c', None, None, None, None, None, None),
 ('d', None, None, None, None, None, None))
In [242]: rows
Out[242]: 
[('Atlanta', 'Georgia', 1.25, 6),
 ('Tallahassee', 'Florida', 2.6, 3),
 ('Sacramento', 'California', 1.7, 5)]
```

I used quite complicated and dull method:

```
frame = DataFrame(rows, columns = list(cursor.description[i][0] for i in range(len(cursor.description))))
```

Is there a short cut to call the column names? Is it possible to achieve this by using zip()?

Comment: `Is it possible to achieve this by using zip()?` .. did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. It's not much better than what you have.

```
columns = list(zip(*cursor.description))[0]
```

Comment: @YannisYuan No problem. Feel free to accept (tick on left) if it was useful.